# which would be better: lists, vectors or deques for CAD type program?

Tags: c++, list, stl, vector, cad

I want to create a something like a simple CAD program in which I can draw circles, lines, squares, etc. Nothing too fancy, just the basic drawing stuff.

I have some thoughts regarding how I could make the program, but I need advice. In a CAD program, one can draw as many rectangles and shapes and remove which ever they want.

I was thinking for every figure drawn (lines, rectangles,polygons) should be an instance of a class and the instance should be stored in a list because I want each shape drawn to have its own properties like color, (x,y) coord, linetype, etc.  For example, 'rect_list' is a container that stores instances from class 'Rectangle'.

For this method of making the program, what would be a better container? `vector`, `list` or `deque`?

Comment: http://kera.name/articles/2010/08/it-is-not-called-the-stl-mmkay/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider a linked list for quick add and remove of entities. With huge lists, when you remove entities here and there, heavy memory operations occur and slow down the entire process...

For selection, in the case of linked list, you need to keep an auto-increment integer value at entity level.

Answer (score 3):

your list of vertexes should be in a vector (once you know the number of points, resize the vector to hold that many and fill it), then you need a list of all these vectors so you can insert into the middle and otherwise manipulate the list efficiently.

However... what you really want is a scene graph. This is a a "tree-view" model that stores a 3d view of the objects, so you can easily see which objects relate to others. They can also show you which objects hide others when displayed (so you don't need to both drawing them), or which are off-screen (ditto).

One of the best is [OpenSceneGraph](http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg), its very STL like.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you go with Qt and play with their [`QGraphicsScene`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html) system. The scene contains [`QGraphicsItem`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html) children, and those can contain further children of their own. The memory and parent-child relationships are handled for you. They also feature spatial indexing so that for example the redraws quickly access only the objects needed. The index also allows quick determination of what objects' bounding boxes intersect, say, the mouse position.

I've recently posted two very [simple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11218063/1329652) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11235761/1329652) of use of particular aspects of the graphics scene/view system in Qt. They are both self-contained code that can be compiled in an empty Qt project in Qt Creator.